# how to prevent init to reinitialize in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to generate an animation with keyboard input. By pressing keyboard, it moves a circle on the screen. My problem is that init part of matplotlib gets re-run and resets the previous value.

```
def init():
patch.center = (0, 0)
print("this section reruns")
ax.add_patch(patch)
return patch,


def animate(i):
  while (True):
    global x, y, k
    x, y = patch.center
    [x,y] = getData()
    patch.center = (x, y)
    return patch,

def showAnimation():
  anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,
                               init_func=init,
                               frames=360,
                               interval=20,
                               blit=True)
  plt.show()
  return anim

try:
  lis = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
  lis.start() # start to listen on a separate thread

except:
  print("error")

while 1:
  test1 = showAnimation()
```

Any advice would be appriciated
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part:

```
while 1:
  test1 = showAnimation()
```

starts the animation every time from the beginning, with the init() function executed.

Don't run the animation in a `while 1` loop, just run it without the loop:

```
test1 = showAnimation()
```